# what is the purpose of return clear in the useEffect i mentioned below?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [timeLeft, setTimeLeft] = useState(10);
  const id = useRef(null);

  // a function to stop the timer 
  const clear = () => clearInterval(id.current);


  useEffect(() =>{
    // getting the id.current to stop the count when it hits 0 
    id.current = setInterval(() =>{
      setTimeLeft((time) => time - 1)
    },1000)
    // ?? why this clear and what it do really 
    return clear     //                                     <--------------------------------
  },[])

  // if timeleft equals to zero , it will the the setInterval
  useEffect(() =>{
    if(timeLeft === 0){
      clear()
    }
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <h1>{timeLeft}</h1>
      {timeLeft > 0 && <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>click</button>}
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

i am trying to get this below output
https://codesandbox.io/s/hooks-useref-clickgame-n1dxp4?file=/src/App.js
i got it finally but anyone explain me why the return clear is needed for it . if i remove it,
timeleft not counts properly. and why useref is needed for it.

Comment: The [docs for `useEffect`'s params](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect#parameters) explains what a returned function is for.